# Kusto/KQL group count and then group by

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm quite new to kql/kusto and using in azure graph explorer. I have the following query:

```
resources 
| join kind=leftouter (ResourceContainers 
| where type=='microsoft.resources/subscriptions' 
| project SubscriptionName=name, subscriptionId) on subscriptionId 
| where type =='microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters' 
| extend properties.agentPoolProfiles
| project id, SubscriptionName,location, name,pool = (properties.agentPoolProfiles)  
| mv-expand pool 
| project id, SubscriptionName,cluster = name, size = pool.vmSize, nodes = pool.['count']
```

This now returns data like:

| cluster | nodes |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 2 |

I simplified the table as there would be the **id**, **subscriptionname**, **size** information as well but I removed to them to make it easier to see the problem.

How could I group by the cluster and count the nodes per cluster and generate a result like

| cluster | nodes |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `sum()` aggregation function:

```
datatable(cluster:string, nodes:long)
[         
    'A', 2,
    'B', 2,
    'A', 2,
]    
| summarize sum(nodes) by cluster
```

| cluster | sum_nodes |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 2 |

Comment: Thanks a lot :) How could I add the additional columns like id, subscriptioname etc. as it seems like not possible to list normal columns in summarize

Comment: I just cheated by putting max(id), max(subscriptionname) etc...is there no other way?

Comment: if they are the same for all occurrences of the same cluster, you can use the `take_any()` aggregation function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/take-any-aggfunction